# Can i disable text chat on Star Wars Squadrons

Tags: star-wars-squadrons

I have read that you can disable voice chat, and communicate with the ping system and emote wheel.  Is it possible to hide text chat like you can in Battlefront 2?

Comment: ok, so far i have found in the list of controls, that if you press **i** on the keyboard that toggles the chat visibility.  so i guess that's the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this article:](https://www.ea.com/games/starwars/squadrons/tips-and-tricks/pc-controls-in-star-wars-squadrons)

> I: Toggle Chat Visibility

To toggle the chat visibility, press i.

Comment: thanks, since thats the official list, I can know for sure.  thanks for the help.